# Search pdf content in google storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, ocr

could you help me with the following? How can I search pdf words hosted on google cloud storage?
example: pdf1, pdf2, pdf3 hosted on storage.
Look for the "father" word in all documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage doesn't allow to check what's inside a document, it's just a Storage service. If you want to search for words in your hosted documents you have to download them to your local machine, Google Compute Instance, Cloud Function, etc. and do the pdf processing there with your tool or language of choice.